# JavaScript doesn't trigger CSS transition

Tags: javascript, css

I have looked throught at least 10 threads here and I didn't find the solution.
What I'm trying to do is change the height property with transition which is supposed to be triggered by my JavaScript code.
That doesn't happen though.

```
nav {
    background: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    display: none;
    height: 0px;
    margin-top: 68px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: height 1s ease;
}



var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
var nav = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0];
var clicks;

button.onclick = function() {
    if (clicks <= 0 || clicks === undefined || clicks === null) {
        nav.style.display = 'block';
        nav.style.height = 'auto';
        bar.style.borderRadius = '0px';
        image.src = 'assets/image/chevron-up.png';
        clicks++;
    }
    else {
        nav.style.display = 'none';
        nav.style.height = '0px';
        bar.style.borderRadius = '0px 0px 15px 15px';
        image.src = 'assets/image/menu-three-horizontal-lines-symbol.png';
        clicks = 0;
    }

}
```

Why? How do I fix this?

Comment: the `auto` value isn't animatable.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work after changing it to 62px, for example.

Comment: and also, the issue is from changing the `display` property as it's not animatable thus no transitions occurs.

Comment: Yes, the display property is what caused the issue. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `auto` value is not animatable, try setting the `height` of the `nav` to a fixed value via it's `scrollHeight` property instead, then it will animate:

```
nav.style.height = nav.scrollHeight + 'px';
```

Also, since you use `overflow: hidden` you don't really need to toggle the display value, and can simple toggle the height value, see this isolated example: https://jsfiddle.net/andreekeberg/xt4pazfd/

Comment: Works perfectly but the magic stops after the first click. The height just changes without any transition again.

Comment: See my update, this is because of `display` not being animatable either.

Comment: I'm going to play with the code, I hope it works! Thank you!

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!